# Pyinstaller is not showing up in the Scripts folder after installing it

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have installed pyinstaller with cmd using the "pip install pyinstaller" command and it says I have it installed but it's not showing in the Python's Scripts folder so it's doesn't work. I tried to install pywin32 and its still not working. I have installer Python 3.9.1 trough the website and added to PATH.
Cmd gives this answer: 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
It's obvilous because pyinstaller.exe is not in the scripts folder. However Powershell gives me this error after the same command: pyinstaller : The term 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pyinstaller --onefile xd.py
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Any sulutions?

Comment: You may have multiple versions of python, thus you'll have multiple versions of pip. On Windows, run `where pip` to see the versions of pip in your PATH. Then make sure you're running the pip you want.

Comment: Thx! Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

**You must allow Pyinstaller to access the project environment:**

1-From dos prompt, digit "windows+r" to open the "Run" window.

2-Digit "cmd" to open the dos prompt and

3-Digit the command **activate.bat** inside the next path:

absolute_path_to_your_project\venv\Scripts\**activate.bat**

This will allow DOS and therefore PyInstaller to access the project environment. After that, if you digit "pip list" will appear the pyinstaller on the list.